# Warning: mysqli_fetch_object() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to add a user-following functionality to my website like twitter's but I keep on getting this error

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_object() expects parameter 1 to be
>   mysqli_result, string given in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ftbindex....

Here is my code, is there any problem with it please?

```
<?php
// show users function

function show_users(){
$users=array();
$sql="SELECT user_id,username FROM users ORDER BY username DESC";                                               while($data=mysqli_fetch_object($sql)){
 $users[$data->user_id] = $data->username;
}
return $users;
}
?>
//end of show users function
//begin display of users in a table
<?php
$users= show_users();
if (count($users)){
?>
<table border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='5' width='500'>
<?php
foreach ($users as $key => $value){
echo "<tr valign='top'>\n";
echo "<td>".$key ."</td>\n";
echo "<td>".$value ." <small><a href='#'>follow</a></small></td>\n";
echo "</tr>\n";
}
?>
</table>
<?php
}else{
?>
<p><b>There are no users in the system!</b></p>
<?php
}
?>
//end
```

Comment: Execute your query first.

Comment: You never actually executing the SQL query.  For examples on how to do that, check the documentation for the function you're trying to use: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php

Comment: also change  $users[$data->user_id] = $data->username to  $users[][$data->user_id] = $data->username; push all values in $users array

Comment: @u_mulder that solved it i had not actually executed the query thanks